# Keyboard Shortcut for a button in adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to implement keyboard shortcuts for buttons in my Adobe Air application.

I have four buttons in a screen. I want to assign <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> keys to them. How to achieve that? I searched a lot but have not found yet.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture key code for F9, F10, F11, F12. For quick, you can get keycode from this site.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_11.html

I saved my all key codes in a constant file. i check pressed button value is equal ko keycode. and dispatched my custom event.

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html) in the LiveDocs. You want to look at the constants.

So you would listen for `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` and do something like this:

```
function keyDownHandler( e:KeyboardEvent ):void {
    switch( e.charCode ) {
        case Keyboard.F9:
            // do something
            break;
        case Keyboard.F10:
            // do something
            break;
        case Keyboard.F11:
            // do something
            break;
    }
}
```